# Decimal precision codefluent

Tags: codefluent

How can I set decimal precision to reduce database size?
I have a decimal value in my codefluent model. The SQL producer produces a decimal (28,13) field for this property. However, I use the property to store values that will never have more than two digits after the decimal seperator and not more than four before. A 28,13 is overkill. How can I force the producer to make it a (6,2) decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Producer specific `size` and `dataType` attributes, like this:

```
<cf:property name="MyNumericProperty"
    typeName="decimal"
    cfps:size="6,2"
    cfps:dataType="numeric"
    xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1"
/>
```

Note that, most of the time, `decimal` is also overkill in .NET (16 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the desired precision for the decimal columns at producer level:

```
<cf:producer name="SQL Server" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
  <cf:configuration
                  decimalScale="2"
                  decimalPrecision="6" />
</cf:producer>
```

The generated column is

```
[Price] [decimal] (6,2) NOT NULL
```

Comment: It looks like I set the precision for all decimals in the project like this. Is that correct? Is there any way to set it for specific properties?

Comment: How can I submit a feature request?

Comment: Please contact SoftFluent by email (support [at] softfluent.com)